# Can't update or publish post/pages with browser Safari

Tags: editor

I have a very weird issue while trying to publish or update a post/page. Each time I try, I have the following error in the Gutenberg editor: "Update failed" or "Publish failed" depending the situation.

The thing is that it only happens with the browser Safari on Mac. I tried with Chrome and Firefox, it works like a charm.

Does anybody know this issue? I'm a Wordpress developer for a few years now and I never saw something similar.

I'm using Wordpress 5.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I deleted the cookies of my website and it works. However I still don't understand why this issue happened.

Comment: Sometimes, it can be with using the administration from secured https to non-https. In my case, sometimes, problems where related to this. You could check the console if they had any issues. Glad you had it worked by resetting cookies.

Comment: Thanks Patrice. The site I've been working on is https. It's possible that the issue was similar to yours.